# thermometer class logic error

Tags: java, class

I'm trying to make a class that has a single constructor that accepts a temperature (in Celsius) as a double, and if the temperature is less than -273.15, it sets it to -273.15. It also calculates other temperatures for different units of measurement, but that's not important. For some reason, I'm getting a logic error that doesn't correct inputs less than -273.15 to -273.15.

```
public class TemperatureC
{


private double temperature;


public TemperatureC(double c)
{
    if (temperature < -273.15)
    {
        temperature = -273.15;
    }
    else
    {
        temperature = c;
    }
}

public TemperatureC()
{
    temperature = -273.15;
}

public double getC()
{
    return temperature;
}

public double getF()
{
    return ((temperature * 1.8) + 32);
}

public double getK()
{
    return (temperature + 273.15);
}

public void setC(double c)
{
    if (temperature >= -273.15)
    {
        temperature = c;
    }

}

}
```

And this is what's using the class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TemperatureTester
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Scanner thermometer = new Scanner(System.in);
TemperatureC temp = new TemperatureC();

System.out.printf("Please enter the initial temperature:");
double intialTemp = thermometer.nextDouble();
temp.setC(intialTemp);

System.out.println("The current temperature in Celsius is:" + temp.getC());
System.out.println("The current temperature in Fahrenheit is:" + temp.getF());
System.out.println("The current temperature in Kelvin is:" + temp.getK());

System.out.printf("Please enter a new temperature:");
double secondTemp = thermometer.nextDouble();
temp.setC(secondTemp);

System.out.println("The current temperature in Celsius is:"+ temp.getC());
System.out.println("The current temperature in Fahrenheit is:"+ temp.getF());
System.out.println("The current temperature in Kelvin is:"+ temp.getK());

}
}
```

And here is my faulty output:

```
Please enter the initial temperature:-900
The current temperature in Celsius is:-900.0
The current temperature in Fahrenheit is:-1588.0
The current temperature in Kelvin is:-626.85
Please enter a new temperature:-900
The current temperature in Celsius is:-900.0
The current temperature in Fahrenheit is:-1588.0
The current temperature in Kelvin is:-626.85
```

It should correct inputs less than -273.15 to -273.15.

Comment: In your constructor, `if (temperature < -273.15)` is checking the default value.  Perhaps you want `if (c < -273.15)` so that you check the value being given to the constructor?

Comment: Yes, the Frog has it right.  `if (temperature < -273.15)` should be `if (c < -273.15)`.  An uninitialised `double` field will be zero, so this condition will never fire.

Comment: I changed `if (temperature < -273.15)` to `if (c < -273.15)` and I'm still getting the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is you are checking the default value of the constructor. Either set temperature to c first or check against c.

```
public TemperatureC(double c)
{

temperature = c;

if (temperature < -273.15)
{
    temperature = -273.15;
}
```

that should work, as a side effect the else is no longer needed

Comment: If I only make that change to my code my output does not change.

Comment: @forjavastuff it might be that you never really call the constructor you call setC instead so this code never actually runs. If you move this check inside the setC it should work. Also as far as i can tell you don't need the constructor.

Comment: @forjavastuff glad i could help you.

Answer (score 0):

You're only checking for temperate < -273.15 in the constructor, so any time you call setC then you won't correct it.  Additionally, in the setC method you don't set the temperature at all unless it's at or above -273.15

You could remove the constructor altogether since you aren't calling it anyway and change the logic in setC to check for temperates < -273.15